# Autorest/Swagger generated code for Web Api controller that returns File

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, swagger

In my ASP.NET Web API application I have a controller like this:

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/ratings")]
    public class RateCostumerController : ApiController
    { 

        [AllowAnonymous]  
        [Route("Report/GetReport")]  
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage ExportReport([FromUri] string costumer)  

        {  
            var rd = new ReportDocument();  

           /*No relevant code here*/

            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray())
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = "Reporte.pdf"
                };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            return result;
        }
}
```

So, when I make a simple GET request with a costumer parameter I get a pdf file in browser as response. Some of the response headers:

Content-Disposition : attachment; filename=Reporte.pdf
Content-Length : 22331
Content-Type : application/octet-stream

After setting up swagger, generated json metadafile and generated C# code with it in my Xamarin PCL project I tried to consume the service.
But it failed because in the generated code is trying to Deserialize json, but is not a json result!

Here it is part of the generated code where it fails:

```
[...]
var _result = new Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationResponse<object>();
            _result.Request = _httpRequest;
            _result.Response = _httpResponse;
            // Deserialize Response
            if ((int)_statusCode == 200)
            {
                _responseContent = await _httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                try
                {
                    _result.Body = Microsoft.Rest.Serialization.SafeJsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(_responseContent, this.Client.DeserializationSettings);
                }
                catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException ex)
                {
                    _httpRequest.Dispose();
                    if (_httpResponse != null)
                    {
                        _httpResponse.Dispose();
                    }
                    throw new Microsoft.Rest.SerializationException("Unable to deserialize the response.", _responseContent, ex);
                }
            }
            if (_shouldTrace)
            {
                Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientTracing.Exit(_invocationId, _result);
            }
            return _result;
[...]
```

When I debugged I figure out that the content of the file is in the body, so deserialization is messing it up. Since is not recommended to edit this generated class file, What I need to change in my API to properly generate the code for application/octet-stream content-response?

Comment: Have you tried using Swagger Codegen to generate the C# API client instead? C# API client geneated by Swagger Codegen should be able to handle `file` download.

Comment: I found code of a filter that made it work. But it still have an issue with the generated code. Once is resolved i'll post it here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a custom filter that returns a file:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class SwaggerFileResponseAttribute : SwaggerResponseAttribute
    {
        public SwaggerFileResponseAttribute(HttpStatusCode statusCode) : base(statusCode)
        {
        }

        public SwaggerFileResponseAttribute(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string description = null, Type type = null)  : base(statusCode, description, type)
        {
        }
        public SwaggerFileResponseAttribute(int statusCode) : base(statusCode)
        {
        }

        public SwaggerFileResponseAttribute(int statusCode, string description = null, Type type = null) : base(statusCode, description, type)
        {
        }
    }
```

And also this custom ResponseTypeFilter class:

```
public sealed class UpdateFileResponseTypeFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            if (apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaultsAttribute>().Any())
            {
                operation.responses.Clear();
            }
            var responseAttributes = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerFileResponseAttribute>()
                .OrderBy(attr => attr.StatusCode);

            foreach (var attr in responseAttributes)
            {
                var statusCode = attr.StatusCode.ToString();

                Schema responseSchema = new Schema { format = "byte", type = "file" };

                operation.produces.Clear();
                operation.produces.Add("application/octet-stream");

                operation.responses[statusCode] = new Response
                {
                    description = attr.Description ?? InferDescriptionFrom(statusCode),
                    schema = responseSchema
                };
            }
        }

        private string InferDescriptionFrom(string statusCode)
        {
            HttpStatusCode enumValue;
            if (Enum.TryParse(statusCode, true, out enumValue))
            {
                return enumValue.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then register it in SwaggerConfig file:

```
c.OperationFilter<UpdateFileResponseTypeFilter>();
```

To use this filter just add it in every action controller like this:

```
 [Route("Report/GetReport/{folio}")]
        [SwaggerFileResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "File Response")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage ExportReport(string folio)
        {
...
```

So, when swagger generates json metadata, autorest will properly create a method that returns a Task < Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationResponse< System.IO.Stream > >

Comment: This is really, really helpful. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 3):

The generated code treats the output of your method as json because the wrong type is written to the swagger.json (probable .... #/definitions/....). It should contain "type": "file"

You can manipulate the output with the SwaggerGen options.

If your method looks like this:

```
    [Produces("application/pdf")]
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Stream))]
    public IActionResult Download()
    {           
        Stream yourFileStream = null; //get file contents here
        return new FileStreamResult(yourFileStream , new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf"))
        {
            FileDownloadName = filename
        };
    }
```

And in your startup where the Swagger generation is setup configure the mapping between the Type you are returning and the Type you want to appear in your Swagger file

```
     services.AddSwaggerGen(
            options =>
            {                   
                options.MapType<System.IO.Stream>(() => new Schema { Type = "file" });
            });
```

Then your generated code looks like this:

```
public async Task<HttpOperationResponse<System.IO.Stream>> DownloadWithHttpMessagesAsync()
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swashbuckle version 4 works for me to create filter:

```
public class FileDownloadOperation : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var rt = context.MethodInfo.ReturnType;
        if (rt == typeof(Stream) || 
            rt == typeof(Task<Stream>) || 
            rt == typeof(FileStreamResult) || 
            rt == typeof(Task<FileStreamResult>))
        {
            operation.Responses["200"] = new Response
            {
                Description = "Success", Schema = new Schema {Type = "file"}
            };
            operation.Produces.Clear();
            operation.Produces.Add("application/octet-stream");
        }
    }
}
```

Assign that into swagger generator

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                ...
                c.OperationFilter<FileDownloadOperation>();
            });
```

And then just have simple controllers:

```
[HttpGet("{fileId}")]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetMyFile(int fileId)
{
    var result = await _fileService.GetFile(fileId);
    return File(result.Stream, result.ContentType, result.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the answer of @Petr Štipek and globalize it :

```
public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
{
    Type type = context.MethodInfo.ReturnType;

    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>))
    {
        type = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

    if (typeof(FileResult).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        Response response = operation.Responses["200"];
        operation.Responses["200"] = new Response
        {
            Description = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response?.Description) ? "Success" : response.Description,
            Schema = new Schema { Type = "file" }
        };
        operation.Produces.Clear();
        operation.Produces.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
.EnableSwagger(c => 
{
    … 
    c.OperationFilter<FileManagementFilter>();
});
```

```cs
public class FileManagementFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.operationId.ToLower().IndexOf("_download") >= 0)
        {
            operation.produces = new[] { "application/octet-stream" };
            operation.responses["200"].schema = new Schema { type = "file", description = "Download file" };
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
[ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
//[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(byte[]))]
[HttpGet, Route("DownloadItemFile")]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadItemFile(int itemId, string fileName)
{
    var result = … 
    return result;
}
```

> *Note:* Action name must ‘Download...’

[image]

Comment: Welcome, and thank you for your contribution. I’ve edited your answer to improve the code formatting; please review so you can format future answers on your own. Additionally, to make this more useful, please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of _why_ this code solves the problem.