# How to save a file to disk from RestSharp through Swagger

Tags: swagger, filestream, restsharp, content-disposition

This question is wee bit similiar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238002/autorest-swagger-generated-code-for-web-api-controller-that-returns-file) and I have used most of the accepted solution including the suggested ResponseTypeFilter.

Specifically my Swagger controller looks like this:

```
    [SwaggerFileResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "File Response")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public void GetFileFromDownloadURL(string r_object_id = null)
    { //Task<Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationResponse<System.IO.Stream>>?

        try
        {
            DocumentumDownloadFile file = new DocumentumDownloadFile();

            string[] r_object_ids = r_object_id.Split(',');
            foreach (string id in r_object_ids)
            {
                string topUrl = "..." + id.Trim() + "/download-url";
                ApiCall documentumCall = new ApiCall();
                IRestResponse response = documentumCall.ApiCaller(topUrl, false);

                JObject jsonres = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                JArray array = (JArray)jsonres["entries"];

                string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"D2"};
                string actual_download_url = "/D2" + array[0]["content"]["url"].ToString().Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
                ApiCall documentumCall2 = new ApiCall();
                IRestResponse downloadResponse = documentumCall2.ApiCaller(actual_download_url, true);


                File.WriteAllBytes("C:\temp\temp.pdf", downloadResponse.RawBytes);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new HttpResponseException(this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "An Error has occured, try again or  contact the administrator"));

        }
```

However, my code failes on the the last File.WriteAllbyte because the downloadResponse.RawBytes is null. This puzzles me because if I run the exact same download-url in Postman and "saves as file" the file is saved as expected. The Response also looks good - the file in question is found, it is just not passed through to the downloadUrl-response.

[image]

So, then I guess I'm doing someting incorrect in my ApiCaller method, which looks like this:

```
public IRestResponse ApiCaller(string topUrl, bool download)
    {
        string url = "..." + topUrl;
        var client = new RestClient(url)
        {
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("...", "..")
        };

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        if (download)
        {
            //var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            //client.DownloadData(request).SaveAs("C:\temp\temp.pdf");
            //var response = client.DownloadData(request);

            var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            var stream = File.Create(tempFile, 1024, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
            request.ResponseWriter = responseStream => responseStream.CopyTo(stream);
            return client.Execute(request);


        }

        else
        {
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;

        }

    }
```

If I remove the File.WriteAllbyte in my Controller I get no errors, but only a Response Body consisting of only "[object Blob]" and Response Code 204 No Content.

I'm thankful for any push in the right direction! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong. The `response = client.Execute(request);` has to be run BEFORE `request.ResponseWriter = responseStream => responseStream.CopyTo(stream);`. Then the response contain byte data and can be returned to the Controller for a File.WriteAllBytes statement.

That was many hours of work for such a small little fix...